# Loop through Elements and find if it has a particular class when page loads

Tags: html, jquery

I have a bunch of class: card inside parent. When the page loads, I want to check each card and if it has a card-header class inside, then this card will be in red.

Somehow my code doesn't work.  Please give me a hand.  Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".parent .card").each(function () {
        if ($(".card").hasClass("card-header")) {
            $(this).css("background", "red");
        } else {
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Item 1</div>
        <div class="card-content">Text 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="">Item 2</div>
        <div class="card-content">Text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Item 3</div>
        <div class="card-content">Text 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `if ($('.card')` you're accessing all `.card`, not just the one in current iteration. Also `hasClass` checks if current element has the specified class, not its children. Instead you can use the [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method to check if an element contains a matching descendant:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent .card').each(function(i, el) {
    const $el = $(el);
    if ($el.has('.card-header').length) {
      $el.css('background', 'red');
    }
  })
})
```

Using the [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector, the whole thing can be shortened to :

```
$('.parent .card:has(.card-header)').css('background', 'red');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent .card:has(.card-header)').css('background', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Item 1</div>
    <div class="card-content">Text 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="">Item 2</div>
    <div class="card-content">Text 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Item 3</div>
    <div class="card-content">Text 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi TJ, thank you very much for clearly explain!  After review your code, I see what I missed.  Would you please explain what `(i, el)` means in each function.  Thanks

Comment: @abcidd `i` is the loop index of current element , `el` is a reference to the element (this reference is a native element so we have to do `$(el)` to convert it into a jQuery element that we can invoke jQuery methods on

Comment: Hi TJ, please let me have another  question: you said `if ($('.card') you're accessing all .card`, if so in this case, do I need to use `each(function)`?  and if I don't have to, Do you have another way to write without using `each`?

Comment: @abcidd  `$(".card") will return all `".card"` elements. Since we are already inside a loop of those, we only want to work with the current element in the loop, so that we can add background to that very specific element, we don't want to add it to all `.card` just because one of them passes the condition, right? Hope that explains better

Answer (score 1):

To target a class given a specific child class, you just need to use `:has()`, specify inside the class `.card-header` as a child.

```
$(".card:has(>.card-header)").css("background", "red");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".card:has(>.card-header)").css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Item 1</div>
        <div class="card-content">Text 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="">Item 2</div>
        <div class="card-content">Text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Item 3</div>
        <div class="card-content">Text 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another solution. You can use the `closest()` method, starting from `.card-header`, targeting the parent with class `.card`.

```
$('.card-header').closest('.card').css("background", "red");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.card-header').closest('.card').css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Item 1</div>
        <div class="card-content">Text 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="">Item 2</div>
        <div class="card-content">Text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Item 3</div>
        <div class="card-content">Text 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi s.kuznetsov, Thank you very much!  Wow, your code is very simple and it works!

Comment: @abcidd, glad to help.